# Can't get blob transparent image into json using php

Tags: php, json, sqlite, blob

```
if (function_exists($_GET['displayResult']))
    displayResult();

function displayResult() {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:ROS.sqlite');
    $sql = 'select * from Item_Image_Large';
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $rows[] = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetchObject()) {
        $rows['Item_Image_Large'][] = $row;
        foreach ($rows as $key => $value) {
            $newArrData[$key] = $rows[$key];
            $newArrData[$key]['image_large'] = base64_encode($rows[$key]['image_large']);
        }
    }

    header('Content-type: image/png');
    $result2 = json_encode($newArrData);
    echo $result2;
}
```

This code is used for get BLOB data from database and try to convert it into JSON format but it doesn’t work. The BLOB data is in PNG format.

Comment: Yes but i cannot get output.

Comment: change your header to header('Content-Type: application/json');

Comment: $rows[$key]['image_large'] shows that it is unable to find any index image_large in your $rows array. so this means that there is a problem in your $rows array

Answer (score 0):

change

```
header('Content-type: image/png');
```

to

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: I try this but i got error like "Undefined index: image_large ". I know this type of error is stand for if "image_large" column is not present in the database. But i have already that column and i have added some blob data in that.

Comment: try out but i got error on line " $newArrData[$key]['image_large'] = base64_encode($rows[$key]['image_large']);"

Comment: now try to check if $rows[$key]['image_large'] contains data or it is empty

Comment: "Notice: Undefined index: image_large in C:\xamp2\htdocs\ros1\readImg.php on line 14" this is type of error is shown when i want output as image.

Comment: bro you need to make sure first that the variable you are trying to encode really has some value.I think the problem is with the foreach loop

Comment: i have try to make change into foreach loop but i didn't get output

Comment: is the size of blob data affect the output?